# CSJS doesn't update property that was set by SSJS

Tags: javascript, xpages

Here is (Yes/No) radio button onChange event CSJS that disables/enables another 'inputOtherRadio' radio button. And it works perfect:

```
rObj = dojo.query("[id$=':inputOtherRadio']");
if(thisEvent.target.value=="Y"){
    rObj.disabled = true;
} else {
    rObj.disabled = false;
}
```

But if I set xPage 'inputOtherRadio' component Disable property = true then the code above doesn't work (it doesn't undisable ...)

```
<xp:radioGroup id="inputOtherRadio" disabled="true">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Y" id="selectItem11"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="N" id="selectItem12"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

How to make CSJS code work for disabled component?

Comment: Solely explanation, but it may help you or someone work out what the answer should be. I suspect that because the radio group has the `disabled` property set to `true`, it's passed to the browser initially as disabled. The CSJS code itself is working still, but the eventHandler doesn't trigger, because the component is disabled, so shouldn't be clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSJS code in first radio button to

```
<xp:radioGroup id="mainRadio" defaultValue="N">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Y"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="N"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return false;]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            options = dojo.query("[name$=inputOtherRadio]");
            for(i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if(thisEvent.target.value=="N"){    
                   options[i].disabled = true;
                } else {
                   options[i].disabled = false;
                }
            }
        ]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:radioGroup>
```

The radio button control gets rendered to

[image]

and as you can see the disabled property is assigned to input elements "Yes" and "No" and not to the whole radio button control. That's why you have to set disabled property for every option.

Comment: It does work in my example. Please check ids of rendered input tags and make sure you use exact the same syntax for setting inputYes like in my code .

Comment: ... and the code has to be in `<xp:this.script><![CDATA[..........]]></xp:this.script>` so that `#{id:inputOtherRadio}` gets replaced on server side before rendering for client.

Comment: Copied your example and it does work for me without any change. Which version you are on? My Domino server is 9.0.1 FP5

Comment: ah.. I forgot.. It's 8.5 :(

Comment: Is it 8.5.3 or really 8.5?

Comment: Updated the code. Now it is working for Domino 8.5.3 too. In 8.5.3 input tags are rendered without `id` so I search for `name` property now.

Comment: Cool.. That works perfect.. Thank you very much Knut

Comment: Glad I could help.